# What is the indefinite integral $\frac{x^{2}}{x-9}$?

Tags: calculus

I tried long division and then integrated and got $\frac{x^{2}}{2}+9x+81\log(x-9)$
I don't think this is right, I don't know what I did wrong.
Please explain the correct way to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to find the definite integral, you need bounds of integration.

Comment: What do you think is right? And if you are looking for a definite integral, what are the limits of integration?

Comment: sorry, i meant indefinite integral

Comment: Why do you think it is not right? You can check correctness, sort of, by differentiating It is actually not quite right when $x\lt 9$. To cover that, you should use $\log(|x-9|)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^2}{x-9}=x+\frac{81}{x-9}+9$$
$$\int (x+\frac{81}{x-9}+9)\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+81\log|(x-9)|+9x+C$$

Comment: yeah thats what I got, but how do you integrate that?

Comment: There's a small error in your answer! Namely with the $\log(x-9)$.

Comment: What about when $x<9$?

Comment: @Lythia Then $\log (x-9)=\log|x-9|+i\text{Arg}(x-9)$
Or if you prefer, $\log (-x)=\log(-1)+\log(x)=i\pi+2\pi i k+\log x$

Comment: @VladimirLenin no. $\int \frac1x dx=\log|x|+C$ not $\log(x)+C$. The integral was incorrect.

Comment: @avid19 Actually, both are antiderivatives. They just differ by a multiple of $i\pi+2\pi i k$ when $x$ is negative.

Comment: @VladimirLenin in an elementary calculus class it is understood that we want purely real antiderivatives. It is confusing and unnecessary to bring up different branch cuts in this context.

Comment: so what is the correct answer?

Comment: @avid19 I see all sorts of students thinking that $\int \frac 1x=\log |x|+C$ in a complex analysis class, while the absolute value makes it only true for one single line of numbers in the complex plane.

Comment: @VladimirLenin I'm sure you do, but we aren't in complex analysis. We're in elementary calculus.

Comment: @avid19 Still, it is important to know that $\int \frac 1x=\log x$, because it is the actual correct derivative. If students just learn that $\int \frac 1x=\log |x|$, then it will be hard to switch.

For example, an elementary science teacher taught a class that the number of neutrons were the same as the number of protons, to "not confuse the class". When the class learned that it was false, they argued that the teacher taught them that and it was correct. So this kind of teaching leads to misinformation and hard adjustments.

Comment: In most elementary calculus classes, the antiderivative will be taught as $\ln|x|$ instead of with log. But in a class already stretched for time, a long diversion into comple analysis is unwise.

Answer (score 2):

In this integral, you can try a kind of substitution:  $$ \int \frac{x^2}{x-9}\, dx $$ Let $ x-9=u $, so $ \frac{du}{dx}=1 $ or $ du=dx $. This implies that: $$ \int \frac{(u+9)²}{u}\,du $$ Now you can separate the polynomial in 3 integrals of simple polynomial : $$ \int \frac{u²+18u+81}{u}\, du $$, i.e., $$ \int u\, du + 18\int 1\, du + 81\int \frac{1}{u}\, du  $$ Finally you 'll get $$ \frac{u²}{2} + 18u + 81 \log|(u)| + C$$ coming back to x  $$ \frac{(x-9)²}{2} + 18(x-9) + 81\log|(x-9)| + C  $$